# How should I fetch data from Youtube Data API with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, youtube-data-api

2023/06/17 Update:already solved.
It's because the JSON format doesn't match with Youtube Data API's.
Here's the update code:

```
struct SearchResponse: Codable {
    let items: [Item]

    struct Item: Codable {
        let snippet: Snippet

        struct Snippet: Codable {
            let title: String
            let thumbnails: Thumbnail
            let resourceId: ResourceId

            struct Thumbnail: Codable {
                let standard: ThumbnailImage

                struct ThumbnailImage: Codable {
                    let url: URL
                }
            }

            struct ResourceId: Codable {
                let videoId: String
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

There are currently two programs, one is ViewModel and the other is ListView.
I hope to be able to find the videos of a playlist by its playlist ID and display them in the ListView.
But the ViewModel can't found the list.

```
//  VideoModel.swift

import Foundation
 
struct Video: Hashable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    let title: String 
    let thumbnailUrl: URL 
    let videoId: String
    var isFavorite: Bool = false 
}


class VideoModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var videos: [Video] = [] 
    
    func fetchData() {
        let playlistId = "PLNhzyV4NWnWPg906ZXTcB8zekuhkTxswK" 
        let apiKey = "my api key"
        let urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet,contentDetails,status&playlistId=PLNhzyV4NWnWPg906ZXTcB8zekuhkTxswK&key=(myapikey)&maxResults=30"

        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                      
                        let searchResponse = try decoder.decode(SearchResponse.self, from: data)
                        var newVideos: [Video] = []
                        for item in searchResponse.items {
                            let newVideo = Video(title: item.snippet.title,
                                                 thumbnailUrl: item.snippet.thumbnails.standard.url,
                                                 videoId: item.snippet.resourceId.videoId)
                            newVideos += [newVideo]
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.videos = newVideos
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
}


struct SearchResponse: Codable {
    let items: [Item]
    let nextPageToken: String
    
    struct Item: Codable {
        let snippet: Snippet
        
        struct Snippet: Codable {
            let title: String
            let thumbnails: Thumbnail
            let resourceId: ResourceId
            
            struct Thumbnail: Codable {
                let standard: ThumbnailImage
                let maxres: ThumbnailImage
                
                struct ThumbnailImage: Codable {
                    let url: URL
                }
            }
            
            struct ResourceId: Codable {
                let videoId: String
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
//  ListView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct ListView: View {
    @StateObject var videoModel = VideoModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                ForEach(videoModel.videos,id: \.id){ video in
                    
                    HStack {
                        if let url = video.thumbnailUrl,
                           let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
                           let thumbnailImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                            Image(uiImage: thumbnailImage)
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 130, height: 70)
                                .background(Color.gray)
                        }
                        Text(video.title)
                            .bold()
                    }
                    .padding(3)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Your song list")
                .onAppear {
                    videoModel.fetchData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct ListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ListView()
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

I have been tried to print them on VideoModel, but output is empty.

```
do {
                      
                        let searchResponse = try decoder.decode(SearchResponse.self, from: data)
                        var newVideos: [Video] = []
                        for item in searchResponse.items {
                            let newVideo = Video(title: item.snippet.title,
                                                 thumbnailUrl: item.snippet.thumbnails.standard.url,
                                                 videoId: item.snippet.resourceId.videoId)
                            newVideos += [newVideo]
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.videos = newVideos
                            **print(searchResponse.items)**
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
```

Comment: In `fetchData()`, you could try using `newVideos.append(newVideo)` instead of
 `newVideos += [newVideo]`.  Also add `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))` just before `do{...}`, to see
 what you are really getting from the server.

Comment: Note the typo in your `urlString`, it should have **\\(apiKey)** not **\\(myapikey)**

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks for your advice! I tried that but it didn't work. I found this error because the json format doesn't match the youtube data api's. I will update in the post!